# Does SQL Server write log files in parallel when multiple databases are involved?

Tags: sql, database-performance

I've read quite a bit now on Stack Overflow and other sites that, with respect to SQL Server, giving a single database multiple log files does not help improve performance. A number of people have separately made blanket statements that splitting one database into many does not improve performance, but they haven't explained why. One of my colleagues insists that using multiple databases does in fact improve performance, because he says that log files can be written in parallel if multiple databases are used, thus reducing the transaction-log-related IO bottleneck. Unfortunately, I can't find anything online--either on SO or otherwise--to clearly support that position.

The web site and associated Windows services I'm developing will receive a huge amount of database traffic, so I've been told I need to split my database into multiple smaller databases so that the transaction logs don't cause a bottleneck (i.e., so, for example, three heavily accessed tables in three separately databases can be updated simultaneously). I'm hesitant to do this because I'd lose the ability to use foreign keys and would thus lose referential integrity.

I sent my colleague a number of links that stated that multiple databases don't improve performance, but he responded back with this one:

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62344/multiple-transaction-log-files-and-performance-impact

Notice how the top answer asserts "Transaction log writes are sequential. Only one of the log files will ever be written to at any one time, so having multiple files - in and of itself - can't possibly change your I/O patterns *for that database*."

Could anyone please shed some light on how transaction log IO works across multiple databases, and whether sequential logging is in fact a per-database limitation?

Comment: This should be migrated to dba stackoverflow site.

Comment: Looks like you're right about that. I don't have the reputation to move it there, myself, unfortunately. Apologies for posting the question in the wrong place.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another link that might be useful: https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/an-xevent-a-day-23-of-31-how-it-works-multiple-transaction-log-files/

The gist of it is, at least with Microsoft SQL Server, you can see using EVENTs that one log is filled before moving to the next (it doesn't even alternate log records between multiple logs), which effectively prevents performance improvements.

I think there are probably edge cases where highly fragmented log files (ie. with many small VLFs) and battery-backup caching controllers where the fragmentation and serial-as-far-as-software-is-concerned writes get parallelized by the controller(s), but I can't think of a real-world scenario where that would provide a performance advantage over using the same controllers and drives in a RAID setup.

Answer (score -1):

SQL Server needs a single sequential log file per database, in order to maintain it's ACID properties.  While you can create a second log file, you probably shouldn't unless under emergency situations, like the drive ran out of space you don't have a better option at the time.

You can see for yourself what SQL Server does with a second log file on a test server.  While under an active workload, watching in something like Resource Monitor or Perfmon, create a second log file.  You'll see a brief amount of activity while it gets allocated and initialized, then the engine will ignore the new file as the virtual log file chain stays in the original file(as long as that file is healthy).  If you have write contention in the log file you way want to stick that single file on a separate dedicated drive that is optimized for sequential write I/O performance probably Raid 10.

For more on Write Ahead Logging and multiple log files see these articles:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186259%28v=sql.105%29.aspx
http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/multiple-log-files-and-why-theyre-bad/

Throwing out the foreign keys is usually a bad idea.  SQL Server can use multiple the database(not log) files actively, you can even stick specific objects to a specific file, and partition single tables into different files.

Really depends on your I/O pattern on how you configure things.  Of course for your situation if your data doesn't need ACID properties and your write performance is the most important thing, you could use some sort of NOSQL database.  Microsoft has been doing a lot of work to bring hadoop into the SQL Server eco system.

It is generally recommended to use multiple database files, check out Paul Randal's blog on sql skills for more information.